# Using the limit definition to find the derivative of this function.

Tags: limits, derivatives

f(x)=sin3x

you have to use the limit definition to find it and I plugged x+h in and everything and I used the sin sum formula but I just can't get rid of the h on the bottom!

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
f'(x)
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin 3(x+h)-\sin(3x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2\cos (3x+\frac32h)\sin \frac32h}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2\cos (3x+\frac32h)\frac32h}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}3\cos (3x+\frac32h)\\
&=3\cos(3x)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\sin(mx)\implies g(x+h)=\sin[m(x+h)]$

Using [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formula,  $$g(x+h)-g(x)=2\sin\frac{mh}2\cos\frac{(2mx+mh)}2$$

Now use $\lim_{(u)\to0}\dfrac{\sin(u)}{(u)}=1$

Observe the three $u$-s within parentheses

Comment: we haven't learned about that formula yet. thanks tho

Comment: @Kaaagome, This gives the cleanest possible derivation, else you can use $\sin(A+B)$ as well