# Finding $d(\sin(3x))/dx$ with the definition of derivative.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, trigonometry

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993033/using-the-limit-definition-to-find-the-derivative-of-this-function/993123#993123) a user claims
\begin{align*}
f'(x)
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin 3(x+h)-\sin(3x)}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2\cos (3x+\frac32h)\sin \frac32h}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2\cos (3x+\frac32h)\frac32h}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}3\cos (3x+\frac32h)\\
&=3\cos(3x)
\end{align*}

How did he get $\frac 32h$ from $\sin(\frac 32h)$?

I don't understand.

Comment: They multiplied $\frac {\frac32h}{\sin \frac 32 h}$ to the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small angle approximation, probably. $\sin(x) \approx x$ for $x$ small.

More rigorously, asymptotic equivalence. Note the well-known limit

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$$

This gives the asymptotic equivalence $\sin(x) \sim x$ as $x \to 0$. This means, within some circumstances, you can interchange $x$ and $\sin(x)$ in limits where $x \to 0$. (In this case, $x=3h/2$.)

---

An alternative angle of approach as pointed out by player3236 in the comments is that they could have multiplied to get a cancellation as so:

$$\require{cancel}\frac{2\cos (3x+\frac32h) \cancel{\sin \frac32h}}{h} \cdot \frac{\frac 3 2 h}{\cancel{\sin \frac 3 2 h}} = \frac{2\cos (3x+\frac32h)\frac32h}{h}$$